# How to calculate energy barrier ΔE in Quantum Espresso?

Tags: quantum-espresso

How do I calculate the energy barrier ΔE along the Li migration path in QUANTUM ESPRESSO?

Comment: Please all all the relevant information for the question. Someone has already voted to close the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.